# Можно ли сказать сиреневатенький?

Tags: словообразование

Можно ли сказать сиреневатенький? Если нет, то как?

Comment: Обычно используют более короткое -- **сиреневенький**. См. примеры: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjquoHz7cDaAhXHFJoKHbXHCXYQ_AUIECgB&biw=1280&bih=601

Comment: Или **сиреневатый**. Примеры: https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=601&tbm=bks&ei=m6zVWoDIFIHE6QTd1JfoDQ&q=%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9&oq=%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9&gs_l=psy-ab.12...47153.52085.0.58598.10.10.0.0.0.0.163.741.7j3.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.lx6Vr9IqS3Y

Comment: Сиреневый — то же, что фиолетовый, сиреневатый — светло- или бледно сиреневый, то же, что светло-фиолетовый или  фиолетовый светлый. Ум.-ласк. от  сиреневатый, если и употребляется, то в быту.

Answer (score 3):

**Сиреневатый** – легкий оттенок сиреневого цвета, суффикс ЕВАТ обозначает неполноту, мягкость качества, например:

Толстяк бережно разложил на столе переданный ему **сиреневатый** бланк...[Дина Рубина. (2008-2009)]

На нем легкий **сиреневатый** пиджак и шелковый тончайший галстук. [А. М. Ремизов. (1917-1924)]

**А что значит сиреневатенький?** Возможно, это еще более легкий, еле заметный оттенок сиреневого цвета. Слова такой структуры имеют разговорный характер, но иногда встречаются в художественных текстах.

Пример:

Из-за шторки просунулся чуть **красноватенький** нос поэта. [Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть (2007)]

Comment: _Jasmin: Слова такой структуры имеют разговорный характер, но иногда встречаются в художественных текстах._ === Встречаются. Но не все. Вопрос был задан по слову **_сиреневатенький_** . Почему же Вы приводите пример с другим словом?

Comment: Я же  сказала, что можно встретить слова такой СТРУКТУРЫ, а не именно это слово, то есть существует модель для их образования. Они понятны, их фонетика несложная, легко выговаривается. А вот словом "сиреневенький" я бы не стала пользоваться: морфемика неясная (не то оттенок, не то ум.-ласкат. значение), и  в Нацкорпусе такого слова нет.